# cordova barcode scanner plugin not loading in iOS after granting camera access

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, cordova-plugins, barcode-scanner

I'm using the [cordova barcode scanner plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/) for my hybrid iOS mobile app. The issue I'm having is on initial use of the scanner, if the user has not granted camera permission it prompts for camera access (as expected). However, it does not bring up the camera or execute any of the callbacks. If you close the app and re-try it will work correctly since it no longer requires a permission check.

I have no experience with Objective C but I've been attempting to narrow down the cause using breakpoints in the following file:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/blob/master/src/ios/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm

LN511 - Adding a breakpoint here is where the prompt appears asking for camera permission. If I then accept the permission while this breakpoint is active and resume execution everything works correctly and the camera UI opens. If I instead continue all execution (it then calls `scanBarcode()`) until its complete and then accept permission the camera does not open and no callbacks are executed.

Has anyone experienced this or have any advice on how I can resolve this issue?

EDIT: I also tried the suggested content security policy but it did not resolve the issue:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:;default-src * 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

EDIT2:
Shouldn't the Obj C code be waiting for camera access to be granted at some point before proceeding?  I can't seem to find it doing that anywhere. Once again I don't know Obj. C so I'm kinda researching as I go, but this sample below (from another SO question) requests access and has a completionHandler.

```
[AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:mediaType completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
    if(granted){
      NSLog(@"Granted access to %@", mediaType);
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Not granted access to %@", mediaType);
    }
```

EDIT3 : JS Code

```
`const scannerOpts = {
                preferFrontCamera: false, // iOS and Android 
                showFlipCameraButton: false, // iOS and Android 
                showTorchButton: true, // iOS and Android 
                torchOn: false, // Android, launch with the torch switched on (if available) 
                prompt: "Place a barcode inside the scan area", // Android 
                resultDisplayDuration: 500, // Android, display scanned text for X ms. 0 suppresses it entirely, default 1500 
                //formats : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED 
                //orientation : "landscape", // Android only (portrait|landscape), default unset so it rotates with the device 
                disableAnimations: true, // iOS 
                disableSuccessBeep: false // iOS 
            };

            cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
                function(scanResult) {
                    debugger;
                    resolve(scanResult);
                },
                function(scanError) {
                    debugger;
                    reject(scanError);
                },
                scannerOpts
            );`
```

Thanks!

Comment: If something is not working as you expect, go to https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues and fill a new issue.

Comment: Yep, I will to but I was also hopeful I might be able to get an answer and submit a pull request (if applicable).

Comment: @jcesarmobile I went ahead and created an issue on the repo. I'll update it if I find anything relevant via this question.

Comment: Can you provide the code (javascript) that you are using to call the scanner? Also, in which iOS version/device are you testing? I'm testing and I get the scan screen before accepting the permissions, but it will remain black until I accept

Comment: iOS10.3.2 iphone7. Added JS code above

Comment: @jcesarmobile my screen goes grey, I see the access prompt, I accept and it returns to my app UI (displaying the spinner I put up before launching the scanner). It never launches the callbacks. If i try to run it again it says a scan is already in progress.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue on 6.0.5 or 6.0.6 on iOS 9 and iOS 10.3.3 devices. Latest version is 6.0.6. Can you try with that version and see if the problem is still present?

Comment: @jcesarmobile What version of cordova are you using? My command line is 6.4.0. My cordova-ios is 4.3

Comment: I've tried with CLI 7, cordova-ios 4.4.0, but I don't think that's the issue. I have used the plugin in previous versions before and never had problems like this.

Comment: @turbo2oh , Do you write  cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan after DeviceReady method?

Comment: @SharmaVishal yes